# Drag and Drop in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, drag-and-drop

There is a simple way to implement a Drag and Drop in VueJS?. I just want to move a div into another. Looking on the web, it seems only to be libraries for making sortable drag and drop

Comment: I use jQuery for it. I didn't find any other convenient way to implement such functionality. But how exactly to implement it depends on your data model and requirements.

Comment: nice example here: https://codepen.io/safx/pen/dasnt

Comment: or use standard HTML5: https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/drag-and-drop-with-html5-368a1bb72881

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic [drag and drop](https://codepen.io/dbrennan/pen/mXdvMe) developed using core javascript.
Hope it helps.

```
class App {

  static init() {

    App.box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0]

    App.box.addEventListener("dragstart", App.dragstart)
    App.box.addEventListener("dragend", App.dragend)

    const containers = document.getElementsByClassName('holder')

    for(const container of containers) {
      container.addEventListener("dragover", App.dragover)
      container.addEventListener("dragenter", App.dragenter)
      container.addEventListener("dragleave", App.dragleave)
      container.addEventListener("drop", App.drop)
    }
  }

  static dragstart() {
    this.className += " held"

    setTimeout(()=>this.className="invisible", 0)
  }

  static dragend() {
    this.className = "box"
  }

  static dragover(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  static dragenter(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.className += " hovered"
  }

  static dragleave() {
    this.className = "holder"
  }

  static drop() {
    this.className = "holder"
    this.append(App.box)
  }

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", App.init)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was asking for a VueJs component.

It seems one of the most used is this one: https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/simple

I can say it works fine.